# Order By SQL - Scala Def

Tags: postgresql, scala

I have the following def in my EngineModel.scala which contains Postgresql SQL. What I would like to do is order by the currency field. I am after assistance to modify/write the code.

I have tried modifying the code with no avail.

```
  def balance(uid: Option[Long], apiKey: Option[String]) = DB.withConnection(db) { implicit c =>
    SQL"""select * from balance($uid, $apiKey)"""().map(row =>
      row[String]("currency") -> (row[BigDecimal]("amount"), row[BigDecimal]("hold"))
    ).toMap
  }
```

Results to then be sorted alphabetically by the field 'currency'.

Comment: Which lib are you using? Have you first tried to design the query by hand in some PostgreSQL tool to check the statement syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using *ScalikeJDBC*, you can simply put an `order by` clause in your SQL query to sort the data based on your needs.

```
  def balance(uid: Option[Long], apiKey: Option[String]) = DB.withConnection(db) { implicit c =>
    SQL"""select * from balance($uid, $apiKey) order by currency ASC"""().map(row =>
      row[String]("currency") -> (row[BigDecimal]("amount"), row[BigDecimal]("hold"))
    ).toMap
  }
```